# Excel: Difference of cell values based on uniqueness of adjacent cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
OPLOAI  OPULL       Desired Output
67  85749217        
69  85749217        2
67  85749222        
67  85749222        
67  85749222        
67  85749222        0
67  85758403            
67  85758403        
67  85758403        
68  85758403        
68  85758403        1
```

For this example, I need a formula to check if column B is a unique value, and if not, return the difference in value of column A between the last instance of the unique value and the first instance of the unique value.  If not unique, return blank.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've tried conditional (IF) functions, looked at some other possibilities within the superuser forums, and attempted to get what I need from the Excel help archives.  None of them got me exactly what I needed.  I have a lot of experience with Excel formulas and some of the more complicated tools, but this one has me stumped.  This is my first post, if this forum isn't appropriate for the topic, I can take it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to approach it:

[image: screenshot]

The formula in C2 is:

```
=IF(B3<>B2,A2-INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(B2,B$2:B2,0)+1),"")
```

**How it works:**

- `IF(B3<>B2,result,"")` checks whether the column B value in the next row is different.  If so, this is the row to display a result, otherwise display a blank cell.
- `MATCH(B2,B$2:B2,0)+1` locates the first row with a matching value in column B.  The MATCH result is relative to the search range, so the +1 adjusts for the location on the worksheet.
- `A2-INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(B2,B$2:B2,0)+1)` calculates the difference between the value in column A for the current row and the value in the first matching row.  INDIRECT builds a cell reference to the first matching row.